# My webview app does not loggin into facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, sdk

I have a web site that is being use in a webView app.

But the login with Facebook in the WebView app is not working.. it send me to facebook login page but then do not returns to the App, and sometimes the screen remains all white..

the login in chrome works OK!

this is my facebook login script:

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXX47035339XXX',
      xfbml      : true,
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function basicAPIRequest() {
    FB.api('/me', 
        {fields: "id,age_range,picture,email,first_name,last_name,gender"}, 
        function(response) {

          $.ajax({
        url: "loginSave.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {id:response.id,
          email:response.email,
          name1:response.first_name,
          name2:response.last_name,
          gender:response.gender} ,
        success: function (response) {

           window.location.href = 'index.php';

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
        }
    );
  }
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery("#load").click(function(e){
    $("#load").css("display","none")
       $("#spinWheel").css("display","block")
    if(typeof(FB) == "undefined") {
        alert("Facebook SDK not yet loaded please wait.")
      }
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {

        basicAPIRequest();



      }
      else {
        FB.login();
      }
    });      
  });


});
```

Comment: check out my answer. side note: you should not use jquery for those basic things, every line of jquery in your code can be replaced by vanilla javascript, with the same amount of lines. also, you should not set css directly, better add/remove classes (with classList).

Comment: ...and for ajax calls, there is fetch (with polyfill) or axios :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in the code:

- You should use `FB.getLoginStatus` right after `FB.init`, to check if the user is authorized on page load
- You should use `FB.login` on user interaction, NOT in the asynchronous callback of `FB.getLoginStatus`. Some browsers may block the login popup.

More information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: great! but how can I save the data of the User in my database without the ajax part?

Comment: the link you provide make the login without pressing the boton, just rigth after the page finish loading.

Comment: no, make sure you understand the difference between getLoginStatus and login. getLoginStatus only checks if the user is authorized already.

Comment: about ajax: fetch IS ajax (and so is axios). it´s just different to jquery ajax. and fetch is a native thing.